# What does -> ? mean at the end of a linux command?

Tags: linux

For example

`Path to MySQL shared libraries directory: 
/usr/local/mysql/lib -> ?`

as seen here: http://www.macports.info/MySQL

Comment: That tutorial refers to Webmin. [Demo installation is here](http://webmin-demo.virtualmin.com/), username and password are `demo`. See the screen at *Servers » MySQL Database Server » Module Config*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that '/usr/local/mysql/lib' is a link that should point to where you have locally installed mysql and it's library folder.

Comment: Why would it appear like that in a Webmin MySQL module configuration guide? Wouldn't it suffice to enter `/usr/local/mysql/lib`?

Comment: It is custom practice to make link such as /usr/local/mysql/lib, so when you get new version of mysql, you only need to update one link

Comment: So is this not a linux directive, but one specific for Webmin?

Comment: Yep. That is correct.